# Asynchronous function inside async.each is not getting fired

Tags: javascript, node.js, asynchronous

Can anyone explain the order in which below console logs are getting printed? I am using async version 1.4.23 .
response contains two items.
output: label 1
        label 2
        label 2
        label 4
        label 3
        label 3

```
async.parallel([
  function(callback){
    detailsData.list({}, function(err, response) {
      if (!err) {
        console.log("label 1");
        async.each(response, function(item, cb) {
          console.log("label 2");
          itemList.getData(item, function(err, response) {
            console.log("label 3");
            }
            cb(err);
          });
        });
      }
      callback(err);
    });  
  },
  function (callback) {
    somefunction();
  }], function (err) {
    console.log("label 4");
  }
```

Why is label 3 not printed before label 4?

Comment: What's `itemList`? How do you know that `getData` isn't being called? Have you run `node debug yourscript.js` to walk through it?

Comment: does `list` has any items in it?

Comment: You're supposed to pass `async.parallel`s `callback` as the third argument to `async.each`, instead of calling it right now

Comment: @Bergi I tried adding callback(err)  as third argument of async.each, but still getiing the same above logs.

Comment: looks like getData is asynchronous so it calls the callback only after you already call the async.each callback. if it returns only a single result per each response try to move cb(err) inside it.

Comment: @user3400887: I meant *pass*  not *call*. See my answer

Answer (score 1):

You will have to pass the `callback` that you get from `async.parallel` to `async.each` instead of invoking it immediately, otherwise the parallel execution won't wait for the each.

```
async.parallel([
  function(callback){
    detailsData.list({}, function(err, response) {
      if (err) return callback(err); // <- still call it when you're not going for the each
      console.log("label 1");
      async.each(response, function(item, cb) {
        console.log("label 2");
        itemList.getData(item, function(err, response) {
          console.log("label 3");
          cb(err, response);
        });
      }, callback);
//       ^^^^^^^^
    });
  },
  function(callback) {
    somefunction();
    callback();
  }
], function(err) {
  console.log("label 4");
});
```

Comment: Thanks @Bergi.. that helped.